# Colors don't stick when lollipop plot is run

Tags: ggplot2

I have created a lollipop chart that I love. However, when the code runs to create the plot, the colors of the lines, segments, and points all change from what they were set to. Everything else runs great, so this isn't the end of the world, but I am trying to stick with a color palette throughout a report.

The colors should be this ("#9a0138", and "#000775" specifically):
[image]

But come out like this:
[image]
Any ideas?

Here is the data:

```r
TabPercentCompliant <- structure(list(Provider_ShortName = c("ProviderA", "ProviderA", "ProviderA", "ProviderB", 
                                      "ProviderB", "ProviderB", "ProviderC", "ProviderC", "ProviderC", "ProviderD"), SubMeasureID = c("AMM2",                                                                                               "FUH7", "HDO", "AMM2", "FUH7", "HDO", "AMM2", "FUH7", "HDO",                                                                                                  "AMM2"), AdaptedCompliant = c(139, 2, 117, 85, 1, 33, 36, 2,                                                                                                                                  22, 43), TotalEligible = c(238, 27, 155, 148, 10, 34, 61, 3,                                                                                                                                                             24, 76), PercentCompliant = c(0.584033613445378, 0.0740740740740741,                                                                                                                                                                                           0.754838709677419, 0.574324324324324, 0.1, 0.970588235294118,                                                                                                                                                                                           0.590163934426229, 0.666666666666667, 0.916666666666667, 0.565789473684211                                                                                                                                                            ), PercentTotalEligible = c(0.00516358587173479, 0.00058578495183546,                                                                                                                                                                                         0.00336283953831467, 0.00321096936561659, 0.000216957389568689,                                                                                                                                                                                        0.000737655124533542, 0.001323440076369, 6.50872168706066e-05,                                                                                                                                                                                         0.000520697734964853, 0.00164887616072203), ClaimsAdjudicatedThrough = structure(c(19024,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           19024, 19024, 19024, 19024, 19024, 19024, 19024, 19024, 19024                                                                                                                                                                                       ), class = "Date"), AdaptedNCQAMean = c(0.57, 0.39, 0.93, 0.57,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.39, 0.93, 0.57, 0.39, 0.93, 0.57), PerformanceLevel = c(0.0140336134453782,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          -0.315925925925926, -0.175161290322581, 0.00432432432432439,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          -0.29, 0.0405882352941176, 0.0201639344262295, 0.276666666666667,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          -0.0133333333333334, -0.00421052631578944)), row.names = c(NA,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

VBP_Report_Date = "2022-09-01"
```

And the code for the plot:

```r
Tab_PercentCompliant %>% 
  filter(ClaimsAdjudicatedThrough == VBP_Report_Date) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Provider_ShortName, 
             y = PercentCompliant)
  ) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Provider_ShortName,
                y = AdaptedNCQAMean,
                group = SubMeasureID,
                color = "#9a0138",
                size = .001)
  ) +
  geom_point(aes(color = "#000775",
                 size = (PercentTotalEligible)
  )
  ) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = Provider_ShortName,
                   xend = Provider_ShortName,
                   y = 0,
                   yend = PercentCompliant,
                   color = "#000775")
  )+
  facet_grid(cols = vars(SubMeasureID),
             scales = "fixed",
             space = "fixed")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(.5, "lines"),
        panel.border = element_rect(
          color = "black", 
          fill = NA, 
          linewidth = .5), 
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(
          color = "gray", 
          linewidth = .5),
        axis.text.x = element_text(
          angle = 65, 
          hjust=1),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_rect(
          color = NULL, 
          fill = "#e1e7fa"))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  labs(title = "Test",
       subtitle = "Test",
       caption = "Test")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an aesthetic constant, it is often easier / better to have it "outside" your `aes` call. If you want to have a legend for your color, then you need to keep it "inside", but you will need to manually set the colors with `+ scale_color/fill_manual`.

I've had to cut down quite a lot in your code to make it work. I've also removed bits that are extraneous to the problem. I've removed line size = 0.001 or the line wasn't visible. I've removed the weird filter step or the plot wasn't possible.

Tips: when defining a global aesthetic with `ggplot(aes(x = ... etc)`, you don't need to specify this aesthetic in each geom layer (those aesthetics will be inherited)- makes a more concise / readable code.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(TabPercentCompliant, aes(x = Provider_ShortName, y = PercentCompliant)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = AdaptedNCQAMean, group = SubMeasureID), 
            color = "#9a0138") +
  geom_point(aes(size = PercentTotalEligible), color = "#000775") +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = Provider_ShortName, y = 0, yend = PercentCompliant), 
                   color = "#000775") +
  facet_grid(~SubMeasureID) +
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(color = NULL, fill = "#e1e7fa"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks tjebo! This did solve my problem! However, perhaps even more valuable, your ggplot tips were incredibly useful. Building this plot was a labor, and along the way more code was added to get closer to the final product. Then, as the true solution became clear, there was a code left over that was no longer needed. Lesson learned. I try and make things as tidy as possible. I learned that for the most part ggplot defaults will do what you need. I'll answer with the final code I'm going with. You'll have to trust me on some of the theme specifications :). Thanks so much for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code. Thanks again tjebo!

```r
# Lollipop Chart ----------------------------------------------------------

Tab_PercentCompliant %>% 
  filter(ClaimsAdjudicatedThrough == VBP_Report_Date) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Provider_ShortName, 
             y = PercentCompliant)
         ) +
  geom_line(aes(y = AdaptedNCQAMean,
                group = SubMeasureID),
                color = "#9a0138"
            ) +
  geom_point(aes(size = PercentTotalEligible),
                 color = "#000775",
            ) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = Provider_ShortName,
                   y = 0,
                   yend = PercentCompliant),
                   color = "#000775"
               )+
  facet_grid(cols = vars(SubMeasureID)
             )+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.text.x = element_text(
          angle = 65, 
          hjust=1),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_rect(
          fill = "#e1e7fa"))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  labs(title = "Test",
       subtitle = "Test",
       caption = "Test")
```

[image]